# python - Letter Count Dict

Tags: python

Write a Python function called `LetterCount()` which takes a string as an argument and returns a dictionary of letter counts.

The line:

```
print LetterCount("Abracadabra, Monsignor")
```

Should produce the output:

```
{'a': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 1, 'r': 3}
```

I tried:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter('Abracadabra, Monsignor')
print c
print list(c.elements())
```

the answer I am getting looks like this

```
{'a': 4, 'r': 3, 'b': 2, 'o': 2, 'n': 2, 'A': 1, 'c: 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, ' ':1, 'i':1, 'M':1 ',':1's': 1, }
['A', 'a','a','a','a','c','b','b','d','g', and so on
```

okay now with this code 
import collections
c = collections.Counter('Abracadabra, Monsignor'.lower())

print c
am getting this
 {'a': 5, 'r': 3, 'b': 2, 'o': 2, 'n': 2, 'c: 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, ' ':1, 'i':1, ',':1's': 1, }

but answer should be this 
 {'a': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 2, 's': 1, 'r': 3}

Comment: looks good? what is the issue?

Comment: cant get it lower case and also last line starting with A is not needed in answer

Comment: @Sarah: How about google: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=python+string+lowercase ? If you don't need the second line then don't print it.

Comment: thanx got that.. still confuse on lowercase letters

Comment: am using 
c.lower() before print c

Comment: thanxx for ur help... c = collections.Counter('Abracadabra, Monsignor'.lower())

Comment: okay now am getting this

Comment: @Sarah: :) Glad to here that... If my answer helped you, please accept it to mark the question as solved (click on the tick outline next to the answer).

Comment: In python you don't have control over the order of elements in a dictionary. If that's all that is wrong your answer is probably correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. Note that in the task description, the case of the letters is not taken into account. They want `{'a': 5}`, where you have `{'a': 4, 'A': 1}`.

So you have to convert the string to lower case first ([I'm sure you will find out how](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=python%20string%20lowercase)).

Comment: @Sarah: As Winston said in his comment, dictionaries are unordered in Python. You cannot influence the way it is printed. Your answer is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary for the letter count:

```
s = "string is an immutable object"
d = {}
for i in s:
    d[i] = d.get(i,0)+1

print d
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, ' ': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 2, 'g': 1, 'i': 3, 'j': 1, 'm': 2, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this to count just letters, exclude spaces and overlook its case and sort them alphabetically?:

```
    t = "The cat is out of the bag."
    word_count = {}

    for i in t.casefold():
        if i.isalnum(): 
            word_count[i] = word_count.get(i,0)+1

    for letter, count in sorted(word_count.items()):
        print(letter, count)
```

Output:
a 2
b 1
c 1
e 2
f 1
g 1
h 2
i 1
o 2
s 1
t 4
u 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).