# Letter Count Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My homework problem is to write a Python function called LetterCount() which takes a string as an argument and returns a dictionary of letter counts. However, my code includes white space and commas as a part of the dictionary which i don't want.
Can you please help me out. How do i remove the white space from my list? Here is my code?

```
import string
def LetterCount(str):
    str= str.lower().strip()
    str = str.strip(string.punctuation)
    list1=list(str)
    lcDict= {}
    for l in list1:
        if l in lcDict:
            lcDict[l] +=1
        else:
            lcDict[l]= 1
    print lcDict

LetterCount("Abracadabra, Monsignor")
```

Comment: Looks suspiciously like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606421/python-letter-count-dict)

Comment: yea i saw that before i posted my question but we never did this code in class. so i am doing it the way i know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check if l is an alphabetic character (`if l.isalpha()`)

Example:

```
   import string
    def LetterCount(str):
            str= str.lower().strip()
            str = str.strip(string.punctuation)
            list1=list(str)
            lcDict= {}
            for l in list1:
                    if l.isalpha():
                            if l in lcDict:
                                    lcDict[l] +=1
                            else:
                                    lcDict[l]= 1
            print lcDict

    LetterCount("Abracadabra, Monsignor")
```

Comment: You should tech him to fish! :)

Comment: IMO in this kind of question, if you pointing the OP to    `l.isalpha()` should be enough, since investigating is part of the learning process... No harm done of course, I don't doubt your intentions are good!

Answer (score 6):

For the letter count, the best way is to use the dictionary.

```
s = "string is an immutable object"
def letter_count(s):
    d = {}
    for i in s:
        d[i] = d.get(i,0)+1
    return d
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, ' ': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 2, 'g': 1, 'i': 3, 'j': 1, 'm': 2, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 2, 's': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 3}
```

Comment: This is an elegant answer.

Answer (score 4):

Extending [python - Letter Count Dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5606421):

```
from collections import Counter

def LetterCount(text):
    return Counter(c for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha())
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you assign the count in the `else` branch, you should check whether `l` is a letter.  Only assign the count if it is a letter.

Comment: i did it by using the .isalpha() method for l and it worked. it was silly not to think of that. thank you i am new to programming and sometimes a little detail slips off my mind.

Answer (score 1):

From python doc (note the leading and trailing aspect):

> string.strip(s[, chars]) Return a copy
>   of the string with leading and
>   trailing characters removed. If chars
>   is omitted or None, whitespace
>   characters are removed. If given and
>   not None, chars must be a string; the
>   characters in the string will be
>   stripped from the both ends of the
>   string this method is called on.
>
> Changed in version 2.2.3: The chars
>   parameter was added. The chars
>   parameter cannot be passed in earlier
>   2.2 versions.

You should take a look at str.replace() and DefaultDict :)

Answer (score 1):

You want `str.translate` instead of `str.strip`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to remove all non-alphabetic characters from the string using `filter()`:

```
filter(str.isalpha, "Abracadabra, Monsignor")
'AbracadabraMonsignor'
```

(Be careful using this in your code -- you shadowed the built-in `str` by a variable of the same name.  Never call a variable `str`.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to do your homework for you because I don't thik it will help you but I'll try to uide you in the right direction, try this out:

```
alphabet = map(chr, range(97, 123))
```

or

```
alphabet2 = list(string.lowercase)
```

`alphabet` and `alphabet2` will contain all the lowercase letters in the alphabet in a list.

<sub>Thanks [eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449449/eumiro) for the remainder!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
def count(string):

    return {i: string.count(i) for i in string}
```

Yet another way

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with...

```py
  string = 'hello'
  d = {}
  for letter in string:
      if letter not in d:
          d[letter] = 0
      d[letter] += 1
  return d
```

Returns

```py
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```